# Redshift COPY from the empty S3 partition

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am using Redshift COPY per S3 partition.

Some partitions exists but have no files (empty): in AWS Console the empty partitions are displayed as

```
date_key=2020-05-28_$folder$
```

In this case COPY command generates the error:

```
error:  The specified S3 prefix 'root/hive/tables/my_table/date_key=2020-06-13/' does not exist
```

One way around it is to check in the code if partition is empty and do not call COPY.

But I hope there is some flag to COPY command (e.g. MAXERROR) which will treat this case as a normal and will not generate an error.

Answer (score 0):

Copy command doesn't throw any error if you are using an s3 path with no files in it. You may need to re-check the existence of s3 path that you are providing in your copy command.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such parameter available by default on the copy parameters in redshift, refer below document from AWS.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY-alphabetical-parm-list.html

Although you can use for each loop or loop in redshift and circle through the directory list of s3 where there is at least one file. Thi directory list you can pass onto the loop to remove this error.